# Comparar y sumar números de un input - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando comparar y sumar dos números metidos desde un input, pero sólo me coge el valor por defecto cuando le doy al botón. Si le vuelvo a dar con otros números no coge la nueva información. ¿Sabéis a que se debe? ¡Gracias!

```js
function sum() {
    var sum = n1 + n2
    h2.textContent = sum
}

function compare() {
    if (n1 == n2) {
        h5.textContent = "Los dos números son iguales"
    }
    else if (n1 < n2) {
        h5.textContent = "El segundo número (" + n2 + ") es mayor"
    }
    else if (n1 > n2) {
        h5.textContent = "El primer número (" + n1 + ") es mayor"
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h2"></h1>
<h1 id="h5"></h1>
<input type="number" name="n1" id="n1" placeholder="Inserta el primer número" value="1">
<input type="number" name="n2" id="n2" placeholder="Interta el segundo número" value="3">
<button id="sumButton" onclick="sum()">Sumar</button>
<button id="compareButton" onclick="compare()">Comparar</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener los valores de n1 y n2 tienes de utilizar el DOM, en tu caso como que haces referencia a un "id" puedes utilizar document.getElementById("n1") para obtener ese valor y operar sobre el etc...

```
let n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
let n2 = document.getElementById("n2");
console.log(n1+n2);
```

También puedes utilizar la librería jQuery para obtener los valores.

Comment: Se me ha olvidado añadir las variables, perdón: 
const h2 = document.getElementById("h2")

var n1 = Number(document.getElementById("n1").value)
var n2 = Number(document.getElementById("n2").value)

Comment: Hola, Amaya. El código que has añadido en tu comentario debería ir en la propia pregunta, por claridad. Por otro lado, la obtención de las variables debería estar dentro de la función que es llamada al hacer click en el botón. De no ser así, las llamadas sucesivas usan los valores antiguos de las variables.

Comment: ¡Gracias, he metido las variables dentro de la función y ha funcionado! (Valga la redundancia XD)